# System.DateTime format as a web service arg

Tags: .net, python, web-services

I would like to use a web service which is written on .NET. 
I should pass a date value to a method `webservicemethod(on_date)`.
It's written in a description that format of this date is `System.DateTime`.
I'm using Python as a client language. After googling I tried to use many combinations but without success. This parameter is a string, but what should this string looks like?

```
from SOAPpy import WSDL
server = WSDL.Proxy('http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?WSDL')
print server.EnumValutes(False)               - works !

print server.GetCursOnDate('1/1/2011')
<SOAPpy.Types.structType GetCursOnDateResponse at 57517192>: {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.Net uses [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) time format when representing (or parsing) it in string format.

Example: `2007-04-05T14:30`

Comment: The same thing :(((( print server.GetCursOnDate('2011-02-05T14:30')
<SOAPpy.Types.structType GetCursOnDateResponse at 57517192>: {}

Comment: Yes, server has a method GetLatestDateTime()                           print server.GetLatestDateTime()
2011-03-16T00:00:00     But it doesn't accept arg in this format :((